# One line LINQ to flatten string[] to a string?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I came up with the foreach below but I am hoping this can be accomplished in one line.. maybe linq? Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
foreach (string item in decoder.AllKeys)
{
    message += String.Format("{0}: {1} ;", item, decoder[item]);
}
```

Comment: Horses for courses.  Your foreach is more readable & terse than anything folk can do with LINQ, I think :)

Comment: what is it that you don't like about the foreach solution?  Is it the nesting braces?  Is it a desire to learn linq syntax?  Is it the declaration of the message variable before the iteration?

Comment: Use the `StringBuilder` class instead of continually concatenating `String`s with +=, to avoid continuous new `String` allocations as `String` are immutable.

Comment: Could you fix the title for this question? You're flattening a dictionary, not an array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var message = string.Join(
    ";", 
    decoder.AllKeys
           .Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1} ", x, decoder[item]))
           .ToArray()
);
```

Comment: One line.  Turns out to be longer than the original.

Comment: @Hogan, that's true but the original represents a string concatenation in a `foreach` loop which could be problematic due to the immutability of strings in .NET. To improve the original a `StringBuilder` should have been used.

Comment: `.ToArray` is unnecessary here i think? `string.Join` works for `IEnumerable<T>` too.

Comment: @Danny Only in .NET 4.0, not in <4.0, the overload was just recently added.

Answer (score 7):

The String class from BCL already supports this. Here is a one liner to achieve this using String class. I would always use the BCL operation if it's available there considering the MS guys would have already taken the pain to optimize such a crucial class.

```
String.Join(";", decoder.AllKeys);
```

Here is the link to the MSDN for all the variants of this method - http://goo.gl/kmwfYt

Comment: The one-liner exactly!

Answer (score 6):

If you're in .NET 4.0, you can use this:

```
string message = string.Join(" ;", decoder.AllKeys
    .Select(k => string.Format("{0}: {1}", k, decoder[k]));
```

If you're not on .NET 4.0 yet, you need to convert the collection to an array:

```
string message = string.Join(" ;", decoder.AllKeys
    .Select(k => string.Format("{0}: {1}", k, decoder[k]).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

```
decoder.AllKeys.Aggregate("", (current, item) => current + String.Format("{0}: {1} ;", item, decoder[item]));
```

Comment: While this is a good translation of the original, this causes an extra string to be created for each item in the array, while using `String.Join` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> query =
  from KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in decoder
  select String.Format("{0}: {1} ;", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

string result = string.Join(null, query);
```

Comment: I think yours is the only answer so far that retains the trailing semicolon, but I suspect that the next line of the OP's code removes it...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Join extension method on IEnumerable like I have:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, values);
}
```

then the rest is just a one-liner:

```
decoder.AllKeys.Select(item => String.Format("{0}: {1}", item, decoder[item])).Join(";");
```

Note that if you're not using .NET 4, then you can replace the implementation of the extension method to whatever works for your version.

*EDIT:*
Even better, create the following extension method:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator, Func<string, string> selector)
{
    return string.Join(separator, values.Select(selector));
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
decoder.AllKeys.Join(";", item => String.Format("{0}: {1}", item, decoder[item]));
```

you won't get more one-line than that, other than putting an extension method on NameValueCollection, or whatever decoder is :)